# Can I invite to share my screen with iOS user?

Tags: ios, messages, screen-sharing

I have noticed Messages App in macOS has the option to share screen, I was just wondering if could use this to share my mac screen with user watching this on iPad/iPhone?
I have tried this, within Messages I clicked Buddies > Invite to Share My Screen and it started loading, but the user hasnt received anything. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I understood you wanted to show something on your screen to a lot of people that are using iOS devices correct?

You also don't want them to have to install another app.

The solution I've in mind is recording your screen with QuickTime. Save it as a small movie and send that movie by iMessage.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used them but RealVNC make a Viewer app for iOS and a Connect app for macOS.
https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/

Comment: Lets say this RealVNC would work, but that is not what I want. I work in company where we all have iPhones and sometimes I just need to quicky share screen and show them something. Understand I communicate to mass so I cannot tell all people to install something, I need something native and ready to use. From what I understand Messages App should allow this but I dont know how :( Perhaps it works only macos > macos way?

Comment: Yes it only works mac-to-mac